# Datatables _empty class

Tags: datatables

I realize that the css class for the empty table (ie: while my data is loading)  is

```
td.dataTables_empty{
whatever css you need here
}
```

Essentially I need to position the loading text to my own percentage due to the fact that my table scrolls left to right so the loading text doesn't appear on the page because it's a large table.

When I attempt to put my css inside that class I use

```
position:absolute;
left:12.5%;
background-color:#93cfff;
```

this works for the one td but I need the background color to cover the entire row. I've tried putting the background color in a tr.datatables class, I've even tried taking the td and tr off completely and just letting it use just the class name, both to no avail. What am I missing here? It's currently showing the color I want for the one TD but the rest of that row is stripped which I dont want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up figuring this out, the stripe was for the div.dataTables_scrollBody class. Putting a background (instead of background-color) in that class fixed the issue.